# Find number of zeros $ x = \ln |x-a| $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find number of zeros $$ x = \ln |x-a| $$
depending on the value of $a$.

### My try

Usually I solve task like that in use of derivatives: 
Let $$f(x) = x - \ln |x-a| $$
Ok now it is time for derivatives and check what is happening
Assume that $f'(x)$ exists... 
$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{(|x-a|)'}{|x-a|} $$
Okay, I see that for $$|x-a| = 0 \rightarrow x=a$$
$f'(x)$ doesn't exists but it is not weird because $f(x)$ doesn't exists too. 
Now I can check different cases for $x<a$, $x>a+1$ and $x \le a+1$ - then I can see behavior of $f$ depending on the value of $a$. But there is some cases to check. 
I wonder if there is a simpler solution, maybe "tricky" one?

Comment: You must use the LambertW-function to find the zeros of this function

Comment: $$x=-{\rm W} \left({{\rm e}^{a}}\right)+a$$ or $$x=-{\rm W} \left(-{{\rm e}^{a}}\right)+a$$

Comment: Do you mean the number of zeros of $x - \ln|x-a|$?

Comment: Yes @MarkFischler, I mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\ln|x-a|$ has two branches (the left branch which is strictly decreasing and the right branch which is strictly increasing). Since these branches are disjoint at $x=a$, we obtain$$\text{number of roots of }(x=\ln|x-a|){=\text{number of intersections of }y=x \text{ with the left branch} \\+\text{number of intersections of }y=x \text{ with the right branch}}$$but from the other side$$\text{number of intersections of }y=x \text{ with the left branch}=1$$which is quite obvious. Now define $$r(a)=\text{number of intersections of }y=x \text{ with the right branch}$$Different scenarios are considerable.

**Case 1 : $a>-1$**

In this case according to the famous inequality $u\ge\ln1+u$ we can write$$x{> x-a-1\\\ge \ln 1+(x-a-1)\\=\ln x-a\\=\ln|x-a|}$$therefore the right branch has no intersection with $y=x$ and $r(a)=0$.

**Case 2 : $a=-1$**

Once more, according to the inequality $u\ge \ln1+u$, **the only intersection happens at $x=0$ therefore $r(a)=1$**.

**Case 3 : $a<-1$**

In this scenario, since $\ln x-a$ is concave and $\ln (x-a)\Big |_{x=0}=\ln (-a)>1=\ln 0=x\Big|_{x=0}$ the there are **exactly two intersections with $y=x$ hence $r(a)=2$**.

> **Conclusion**
>
> The final formula for number of roots of $x-\ln|x-a|$
>   is:$$r(a)=\begin{cases}1&,\quad a>-1\\2&,\quad a=-1\\3&,\quad
>  a<-1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Graph $\ln (s)$ for $s > 0$.  An examination of the derivative w.r.t. $s$ shows that the function is strictly increasing, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  Therefore, there can be only one zero, which is known to be $s = 1$.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the OP is considering $\ln(|x-a|)$ rather than $\ln(x-a)$. For example, if $a=-2$ then there are three solutions to the given equation (by looking at a graph).

Comment: I think you answered what the question said, but not what the OP meant to ask.

Comment: @Dave, the main nuance is that $\ln$ is a multi-branch function, and the answer depends on the choice of branch(es).  I limited my answer to one branch, hinting that each branch should be separately examined for zeros.  Incidentally, these branches coincide with the subdomains on which the modulus function is differentiable, resolving another difficulty noted by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The function will either have one root, two or three roots. You must determine the local minimum $x^*$. If $f(x^*)<0$ there will be three roots, if $f(x^*)=0$ there will be two roots and if $f(x^*)>0$ there will be a single root.

Naturally, $x^*$ will depend on $a$. The local minimum will occur in $]a, +\infty[$, so

$$
f'(x^*)=0 \Leftrightarrow 1- \frac{1}{x^*-a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{x^*-a-1}{x^*-a} = 0 \Leftrightarrow x^* =1+a.
$$.

So, knowing the sign of $f(1+a)$ you can decide how many zeros there are. Since $f(a+1)=a+1$, there will be a single root if $a>-1$, two roots if $a=-1$ and three roots if $a< -1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice problem.  There is always one zero at positive $x$. But the answer is that there are $3$ zeros when $a<-1$, two of which come at opposite sides of the vertical line $x = a$, two zeros when $a = -1$ coming at $x\approx -1.278$ and $x=0$, and just the one positive one solution when $a>-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=x-\ln\lvert x-a\rvert$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{a\}$. Consider that
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty,\quad
\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=\infty,\quad
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\infty,\quad
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x-a}=\frac{x-a-1}{x-a}
$$
For $x<a$, we also have $x<a+1$, so $f'(x)>0$. Hence, because of the limits above, there is a zero of $f$ in the interval $(-\infty,a)$.

For $x>a$, the function has a minimum at $a+1$. Since
$$
f(a+1)=a+1
$$
you should be able to finish.

> this minimum is negative for $a<-1$: two zeros; zero for $a=-1$: one zero; positive for $a>-1$: no zero.

You can also simplify the task by considering $g(x)=x+a-\ln\lvert x\rvert$, that has the same number of zeros. The derivative is $g'(x)=1-1/x=(x-1)/x$, so there is a minimum at $1$.