# Number of solutions of $\ln(|a-x|)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I don't want to duplicate this question:
[which is too similar to post it again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155836/find-number-of-zeros-x-ln-x-a)
but could you explain to me, how do we determine the number of root in the interval, using the derivative?

I have tried substitution with:

$$ y=a-x\\x=a-y~~for~x>0\\x=y-a~~for~x<0\\x>0\\f(y)=\ln(y)+y-a\\f'(y)=\frac{1}{y}+1\\f'(y)=0~~~y=-1\\\\f'(y)>0~~~y<-1\\\\f'(y)<0~~~y>-1\\min=0$$

Then I substitute:
$$\ f(-1)=a+1$$
Thus $f(-1)=0$ for $a=1$. Similarly I construct the answers for $x<0$. However, **how to determine the number of roots for every interval of a?**

Comment: +1 for the way you presented a perfectly legitimate question.  In effect, you are saying that the query already has an answer, you have researched the answer, and you have questions about it - a very reasonable position.  By the way, personally, I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation can be splitted in two parts
$$\ln(a-x)=x,\quad x<a$$
$$\ln(x-a)=x,\quad x>a$$
The first equation has one and only one solution for any value of $a$.

consider $f(x)=\ln(a-x)-x$

Its derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}-1$ which is negative for $x<a$. Thus $f(x)$ is decreasing and its range is $(-\infty,\infty)$ so for the intermediate value theorem it assumes once and only once the value $f(x)=0$

For the second equation consider $g(x) = \ln(x-a)-x$.

$$  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a^ +  } \ln \left( {x - a} \right) - x =  - \infty  $$
$$
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \ln \left( {x - a} \right) - x =  - \infty 
$$

We have $$g'(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}-1=\frac{1-x+a}{x-a}$$

$g'(x) = 0 $ for $x=1+a$ and we can see that this is a point of maximum since $g'(x)<0$ for $x>1+a$ and $g'(x)>0$ for $a<x<1+a$.

For $a=-1$ we have $x=0, g(0)=0$ and the tangent in $(0,0)$ is $y=0$. One single intersection.

$y$-value of the point of maximum is $g(1+a)=\ln(1+a-a)-1-a=-1-a>0$ for $-1-a>0\to a<-1$.

So $g(x)$ has two roots for $a<-1$ because second derivative is $g''(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}$ and is negative for any $x$, which means that concavity is down on all the function's domain. Therefore $g(x)$ must intersect $y$-axis in two points because the limits at $a^+$ and $+\infty$ are both $-\infty$.

Therefore $g(x)$ has no roots for $a>-1$, one root for $a=-1$ and two roots for $a<-1$.

In conclusion we can say that the given equation
$$\ln|a-x|=x$$
has three roots for $a<-1$, two roots for $a=-1$ and one root for $a>-1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks awesome. However, how do we see that this is tangent for $a=-1$?

Comment: And why g'(x)<0 for a<x<a+1? It looks positive for me.

Comment: @Funny Sorry, I messed up with $LaTeX$. I have edited the correction

Comment: Could you explain how do we see a=-1?

Comment: @Funny I edited my answer. Hope it is more clear now

Comment: Thank you, it's more clear and detailed

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be rewritten

$$a=x\pm e^x.$$

The branch $x+e^x$ is monotonic, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and contributes one root for all $a$.

The branch $x-e^x$ has a maximum at $x=0$, where $a=-1$. For $a<-1$, that makes two roots, and one for $a=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note first that for *any* $a$, there will always be exactly one point in the decreasing part of $y = ln|x-a|$ (i.e. $x<a$), that intersects the line $y=x$. So it remains to determine how many points of intersection there are of the graph $y = ln|x-a|$ and $y = x$ for the *increasing* part of the graph $y = ln|x-a|$ (i.e. $x>a$).

Given $a$, we want to find the unique point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the graph of $y = ln|x-a|$ with gradient $1$. Then one of 3 things is possible:

1. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 > y_1:}\ (x_1,y_1)$ lies "underneath" the line $y=x$, in which case there is *no* solution to $ln|x-a| = x$ on the increasing part of the graph.
2. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 = y_1:}\ (x_1,y_1)$ lies "on" the line $y=x$, in which case $(x_1,y_1)$ is the *only* solution to $ln|x-a| = x$ on the increasing part of the graph  and $(x_1,y_1) = (0,0)$.
3. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 < y_1:}\ (x_1,y_1)$ lies "above" the line $y=x$, in which case there are two solution to $ln|x-a| = x$ on the increasing part of the graph: one is in the first quadrant and one is in the 3rd quadrant.

Now let's get to the differentiation stuff.

$f(x) = ln|x-a| \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{x-a},\ a \neq 0. \quad f'(x_1) = 1 \implies \frac{1}{x_1-a} = 1 \implies x_1 = 1-a \implies y_1 = ln|1| = 0, \ \therefore \text{point with} \ m = 1 \ \text{on} \ y = ln|x-a| \ \text{is} \ (x_1,y_1) = (1+a,0).$

$$$$

1. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 > y_1}\ \implies 1+a >0 \implies a>-1$. From the graph below, we see there is one solution to $ln|x-a| = x $ when $a>-1$.

[image]

$$$$

2. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 = y_1}\ \implies a=-1$. From the graph below, we see there are two solutions to $ln|x-a| = x$ when $a=-1$.

[image]

$$$$

3. $\bbox[yellow]{x_1 < y_1}\ \implies a<-1$. From the graph below, we see there are three solutions to $ln|x-a| = x$ when $a<-1$.

[image]

Comment: Nevertheless, it looks great. Thank you!